# Multi-Cell LiOn Charging Station Safety Considerations?

Tags: battery-charging, physical-design

I am designing a 20 cell LiOn charging station (20 cells per circuit board).

I am curious if anyone has designed such a solution and the type of enclosure you used (plastic enclosure, metal, etc)?
Likewise, any non-obvious things to take into consideration?